# Fancybox can't open partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I want to open partial view in fancybox like a modal view but when I click on the link it opens whole new page but it should open that in fancybox.
I don't know if this is important but I have one more function that open images in fancybox (on the same page) and it works. Class names are different

```
@Html.ActionLink("Feedback", "New", "Feedback", null, new { @class = "lightbox" })
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lightbox').fancybox();
    // Another light box that works
    $(".fancybox-button").fancybox({...
```

Action method

```
public ActionResult New()
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

I also get this error in browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /Feedback/New
m.errorjquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
m.filterjquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
mjquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
c.querySelectorAll.mjquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
f.fn.extend.findjquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
e.fn.e.initjquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
ejquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
e.extend._startjquery.fancybox.pack.js:14
e.extend.openjquery.fancybox.pack.js:6
e.fn.fancybox.fjquery.fancybox.pack.js:33
f.event.dispatchjquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i
```

Code from separate demo project

```
<script src="@Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Scripts/fancyapps-fancyBox-5403ca0/source/jquery.fancybox.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/fancyapps-fancyBox-5403ca0/source/jquery.fancybox.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/fancyapps-fancyBox-5403ca0/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DOM is ready when attaching the fancybox:

```
$(function() {
    $('.lightbox').fancybox();
});
```

Also make sure that the jQuery and fancybox scripts are properly referenced prior to the script in which you attempt to attach the fancybox.

Comment: I have updated question. JS code for fancybox is in the $(document).ready. I also tried to add jquery reference in this page (but it's already in layout page) but nothing. What is wired is that another fancybox items works fine (images).

Comment: Is the controller action being hit? Do you have a corresponding view: `~/Views/Feedback/New.cshml`?

Comment: No. But when I add jquery reference on this page then hit it. But not open page in fancybox it opens it as a new page.

Comment: The code you have posted looks fine. The problem lies in some other part of your code.

Comment: I created completely new mvc project and did the same and I get same error. In question I have added all references that I add...

Comment: Why are you including the fancybox script twice?

Comment: By mistake. But that is not the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for some reason when my actionlink was placed inside an `<li>` element.

Pulled it out and the error went away, fancybox opened as expected

Is your actionlink in an `<li>`?